# How do I make the Ansible to_datetime filter work inside a loop by using variables

Tags: date, time, ansible

I have a list of items with dates which need to be subtracted to figure out the number of days. Check below.

```
  - name: dump result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ( (ansible_date_time.date|to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')) - (item['date'] | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')) ).days  }}"
    with_items: "{{ key_val }}"
```

Except this Causes the following error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({u'msg': u\"{{ item['date'] | to_datetime }}\"}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: time data 'Time Start' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/script.yml': line 26, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: dump result\n      ^ here\n"}

Even if I run it as follows, I get the same error:

```
msg: "{{ item['date'] | to_datetime }}"
```

The Structure of the item['date'] is as follows:

```
"2019-02-21 15:33:17"
```

If I use the string and manually debug it with a msg, it works:

```
"{{ ('2019-02-21 15:33:17' | to_datetime) }}"
```

I feel like when I introduce a variable, it messes up. Any advice for using variables?

---

When I run:

```
- name: dump result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item['date'] }}"
  with_items: "{{ key_val }}"
```

I get:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'date': u'2019-02-21 10:13:02', 'id': u'7ae7ec89-1f59-4c89-8d56-36901c2c2d28'}) => {
    "msg": "2019-02-21 10:13:02"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'date': u'2019-02-21 10:20:11', 'id': u'b8374680-1305-4b08-b14c-ae31cd7a7ce7'}) => {
    "msg": "2019-02-21 10:20:11"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'date': u'2019-02-21 10:20:39', 'id': u'95521c1b-d2e0-4f8d-bb55-20a2509f5214'}) => {
    "msg": "2019-02-21 10:20:39"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'date': u'2019-02-21 10:20:44', 'id': u'caf668b1-f457-4efc-aa34-1a9f45218490'}) => {
    "msg": "2019-02-21 10:20:44"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'date': u'2019-02-21 10:20:47', 'id': u'0dc43b92-0eb2-4ee4-8889-15148c182c01'}) => {
    "msg": "2019-02-21 10:20:47"
}
```

Comment: Provide *complete* MCVE. `key_val` variable name suggests that `item['date']` is not a string.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I've added the results of doing a debug on item['date'], check my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of my values had bogus strings that did not have a %Y-%m-%d structure. Fixed and functional.